how to pass variable to other method in other controller in laravel 10
i want pass $data_B from controller1 to methodReceive in Controller2
how to send data from methodAbc Controller1 to methodReceive Controller2
i have this code
Controller 1 :
namespace App\Http\Controllers
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

Class Controller1 extend Controller{
public function methodAbc(){
$data_A = ['A','B','C'];
$data_B = ['Data1', 'Data2', 'Data2'];

// i need logic here

return $this->sendResponse($data_A, 'Successfully', 200);
}
}

Controller 2 :
namespace App\Http\Controllers
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

Class Controller2 extend Controller{
public function methodReceive($data1, $data2, $data3) {
$data1 = $data1;
$data2 = $data2;
$data3 = $data3;
return response()->json(compact(['data1','data2','data3']));
}
}


Best way to do it is to use the Service-Class.You also send data using Dependency-Injection either through constructor-function or through method of the controller.No matter which method you use ,you can't use return twice since return terminate the code execution.

oke solve with using app(Controller::)
